# How do I get my page title to have an icon?

Tags: html, icons

I would like to have my site’s logo shown in the icon area of the title rather than the default white document. Exactly as Stack Overflow has it.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

add this to your HTML Head.
Of course the file "favicon.ico" has to exist.
I think 16x16 or 32x32 pixel files are best.

Comment: For the code, I think wikipedia has a better explanation and better cross browser compatibility.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: Thanks!
Just took this codeline from my Website and since it works, I thought it can't be too wrong. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Nick!  Kust had to convert my image to an ico to get it working in IE.

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/images/MyIcon.ico" />

Comment: If using in ruby rails `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<%= asset_path('icon_name.jpg')%>">`

Answer (score 21):

this is an interesting question so let check it 
if you have a image for use as a website-icon then

Add this to your script

```
   <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif" />
```

otherwise if you have a icon for your website icon then you chose

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I always use http://www.iconspedia.com/ for more icons

if my answer solved your problem then give me vote 
ok

Answer (score 8):

They're called favicons, and are quite easy to make/use. Have a read of http://www.favicon.com/ for help.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently you can use this trick.

```
<title> My title</title>
```

That icon-alike is actually a text.

Comment: Where do you find these?

Comment: There's a [minor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55391481/6282576) with this approach.

Answer (score 8):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417490/6282576) works perfectly fine. I just want to mention a minor problem with the [answer devXen has given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794080/6282576).

If you set the icon like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico">
```

The icon will work as expected:

[image]

However, if you set it like [devXen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50021/devxen) has suggested:

```
<title> Amir A. Shabani</title>
```

The title of the page moves upon refresh:

[image]

So I would advise using `<link>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[According to w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp):

```
<link rel="icon" href="your_icon"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will definitely work. In a comment I saw they are using a 'js' syntax that is not for everyone only for those who are working with 'express.js'

```
<link rel="icon" href="demo_icon.gif" sizes="16x16">
<title> Reddit</title>
```

you can also add png and jpg

Answer (score 1):

If using in ruby rails use the below code.

For calculating the path of the file, asset_path function is used to find the image that we are using inside of the rails code embedded in `<%= code %>`

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<%= asset_path('icon_name.jpg')%>">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use a URL just you can use this code.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://..." />
```